# Find inverse matrix for Vandermonde matrix using Cramer's rule

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing, determinant, inverse

I want to prove that I can find the inverse matrix for a Vandermonde matrix using Cramer's rule.

Let $A$ be a Vandermonde matrix, and $b$ the first column of the identity matrix $I$.

When I solve $Ax=b$ with Cramer's rule, is it true that $x$ is the first column in $A^{-1}$?

So I get matrix $X$, and $AX = I$.

Unfortunately, I don't know whether it is right or not that $XA = I$?

Comment: You may be interested in proofs that $AX=I\implies XA=I$ when $A$ and $X$ are $n$-by-$n$ matrices: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3852/if-ab-i-then-ba-i